# Remote QBGLvideoView not working when video calling using WebRTC QuickBlox in Android

Tags: android, quickblox

I am working on `WebRTC` using `QuickBlox` in Android. I have followed the tutorial [here](http://quickblox.com/developers/Sample-webrtc-android). I am able to call from one device to another  i.e When I call from device A to Device B,I can see my video in the `local` `QBGLVideoView` but I am not able to see the other person's video on the `remote` `QBGLVideoView`. The same scenario happens on device B. Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong.My full code are as below:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnClickListener,
    QBRTCClientSessionCallbacks, QBRTCClientConnectionCallbacks,
    QBRTCClientVideoTracksCallbacks {
Button sign_up, btn_login, btn_call, btn_recieve, btn_login2;
QBChatService chatService;
final QBUser user1 = new QBUser("temp151", "123456789");
final QBUser user2 = new QBUser("temp152", "123456789");

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    QBSettings.getInstance().fastConfigInit("xxxxxx", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");

    sign_up = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sign_up);
    btn_login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
    btn_call = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_call);
    btn_recieve = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_recieve);
    btn_login2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_login2);
    sign_up.setOnClickListener(MainActivity.this);
    btn_login.setOnClickListener(MainActivity.this);
    btn_call.setOnClickListener(MainActivity.this);
    btn_recieve.setOnClickListener(MainActivity.this);
    btn_login2.setOnClickListener(MainActivity.this);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.sign_up:
        QBAuth.createSession(new QBEntityCallback<QBSession>() {

            @Override
            public void onError(List<String> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.i("error", "" + arg0);
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                user1.setFullName("temp151");
                user1.setPhone("123456789");

                QBUsers.signUp(user1, new QBEntityCallbackImpl<QBUser>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(QBUser user, Bundle args) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(List<String> errors) {

                    }
                });

            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(final QBSession session, Bundle arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                final QBUser user1 = new QBUser("temp151", "123456789");

                user1.setFullName("temp151");
                user1.setPhone("123456789");

                QBUsers.signUp(user1, new QBEntityCallbackImpl<QBUser>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(QBUser user, Bundle args) {
                        user1.setId(session.getUserId());
                        if (!QBChatService.isInitialized()) {
                            QBChatService.init(MainActivity.this);
                            chatService = QBChatService.getInstance();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(List<String> errors) {

                    }
                });
            }
        });

        break;
    case R.id.btn_login:
        create_session();
        break;
    case R.id.btn_call:

        QBRTCTypes.QBConferenceType qbConferenceType = QBConferenceType.QB_CONFERENCE_TYPE_VIDEO;
        List<Integer> opponents = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        opponents.add(4319012); // QBUser ID

        Map<String, String> userInfo = new HashMap<>();
        userInfo.put("user", "temp152");

        // Init session
        QBRTCSession session = QBRTCClient.getInstance()
                .createNewSessionWithOpponents(opponents, qbConferenceType);

        // Start call
        session.startCall(userInfo);

        break;
    case R.id.btn_recieve:

        // VideoChatConfig videoChatConfig =
        // QBVideoChatController.getInstance().callFriend(user2,
        // CallType.VIDEO_AUDIO, null);

        break;
    case R.id.btn_login2:

        QBAuth.createSession(user2, new QBEntityCallback<QBSession>() {

            @Override
            public void onError(List<String> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(QBSession arg0, Bundle arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                user2.setId(arg0.getUserId());
                if (!QBChatService.isInitialized()) {
                    QBChatService.init(MainActivity.this);
                    chatService = QBChatService.getInstance();
                }
                chatService.login(user2,
                        new QBEntityCallbackImpl<QBUser>() {

                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess() {
                                // success
                                // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                // "Login successful" , 1000).show();
                                Log.e("Login Successful", "Logged In");

                                create_SignallingManager();
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onError(List errors) {
                                // error
                                Log.i("errors", "" + errors.toString());
                            }
                        });
            }
        });

        break;
    default:
        break;
    }

}

public void create_SignallingManager() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    QBRTCClient.getInstance()
            .addSessionCallbacksListener(MainActivity.this);
    QBRTCClient.getInstance().addConnectionCallbacksListener(this);
    QBRTCClient.getInstance().addVideoTrackCallbacksListener(this);

    QBRTCClient.getInstance().prepareToProcessCalls(this);
    QBChatService
            .getInstance()
            .getVideoChatWebRTCSignalingManager()
            .addSignalingManagerListener(
                    new QBVideoChatSignalingManagerListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void signalingCreated(
                                QBSignaling qbSignaling,
                                boolean createdLocally) {
                            if (!createdLocally) {
                                QBRTCClient.getInstance().addSignaling(
                                        (QBWebRTCSignaling) qbSignaling);
                            } else {
                                QBRTCClient.getInstance().addSignaling(
                                        (QBWebRTCSignaling) qbSignaling);
                                try {

                                    QBVideoChatController
                                            .getInstance()
                                            .initQBVideoChatMessageListener();
                                } catch (XMPPException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }

                            }
                        }
                    });

    /*
     * SessionCallback loginlistener = new SessionCallback() {
     * 
     * @Override public void sessionCreated(InputMethodSession arg0) { //
     * TODO Auto-generated method stub try {
     * 
     * QBVideoChatController.getInstance()
     * .initQBVideoChatMessageListener(); } catch (XMPPException e) {
     * e.printStackTrace(); }
     * 
     * }
     * 
     * };
     */
}

public void create_session() {
    QBAuth.createSession(user1, new QBEntityCallback<QBSession>() {

        @Override
        public void onError(List<String> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(QBSession arg0, Bundle arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            user1.setId(arg0.getUserId());
            if (!QBChatService.isInitialized()) {
                QBChatService.init(MainActivity.this);
                chatService = QBChatService.getInstance();
            }
            chatService.login(user1, new QBEntityCallbackImpl<QBUser>() {

                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {
                    // success
                    Log.i("Login Successful", "Logged In");
                    // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    // "Login successful" , 1000).show();

                    create_SignallingManager();

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(List errors) {
                    // error
                    Log.i("errors", "" + errors.toString());
                }
            });
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onCallRejectByUser(QBRTCSession arg0, Integer arg1,
        Map<String, String> arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onReceiveHangUpFromUser(QBRTCSession arg0, Integer arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // oast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "On hang up", 1000).show();
}

@Override
public void onReceiveNewSession(QBRTCSession arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Map<String, String> userInfo = arg0.getUserInfo();// new HashMap<String,
                                                        // String>();
    // userInfo.put("user", "temp152");

    // Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "OnReceive", 1000).show();
    // Accept incoming call
    arg0.acceptCall(userInfo);
    arg0.setVideoEnabled(true);

}

@Override
public void onSessionClosed(QBRTCSession arg0) {
    // QBRTCClient.getInstance().removeVideoTrackCallbacksListener(MainActivity.this);
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onSessionStartClose(QBRTCSession arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onUserNotAnswer(QBRTCSession arg0, Integer arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onConnectedToUser(QBRTCSession arg0, Integer arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.i("connected to second user", "connected");
}

@Override
public void onConnectionClosedForUser(QBRTCSession arg0, Integer arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailedWithUser(QBRTCSession arg0, Integer arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onDisconnectedFromUser(QBRTCSession arg0, Integer arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onDisconnectedTimeoutFromUser(QBRTCSession arg0, Integer arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onError(QBRTCSession arg0, QBRTCException arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.i("Error", "" + arg1.toString());

}

@Override
public void onStartConnectToUser(QBRTCSession arg0, Integer arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.i("Connection", "connecting to user");

}

@Override
public void onLocalVideoTrackReceive(QBRTCSession arg0, QBRTCVideoTrack arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    QBGLVideoView localVideoVidew = (QBGLVideoView) findViewById(R.id.localVideoView);
    VideoRenderer localRenderer = new VideoRenderer(new VideoCallBacks(
            localVideoVidew, QBGLVideoView.Endpoint.LOCAL));
    arg1.addRenderer(localRenderer);
    localVideoVidew.setVideoTrack(arg1, QBGLVideoView.Endpoint.LOCAL);
}

@Override
public void onRemoteVideoTrackReceive(QBRTCSession arg0,
        QBRTCVideoTrack remoteVideoTrack, Integer arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    // Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Onremote", 1000).show();

    QBGLVideoView remoteVideoView = (QBGLVideoView) findViewById(R.id.remoteVideoView);
    VideoRenderer remoteRenderer = new VideoRenderer(new VideoCallBacks(
            remoteVideoView, QBGLVideoView.Endpoint.REMOTE));
    arg0.setVideoEnabled(true);
    arg0.setAudioEnabled(true);

    remoteVideoTrack.addRenderer(remoteRenderer);
    remoteVideoView.setVideoTrack(remoteVideoTrack,
            QBGLVideoView.Endpoint.REMOTE);

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Looks like everything right. Did you check your layouts, because as you can see QBGLVideoView instance works as usual View (GLSurfaceView). Maybe, problem in UI.
If you can, please add file with android logs in the conversation.